# Using separate functions on different collision categories

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently designing a game (iOS Swift, Sprite Kit) with three SKPhysics-categories:

1. Player
2. Objects
3. Platforms

When a collision between either one of these categories occurs, the follow function runs:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    println("Collision")
    self.gameOver = true

}
```

This is fine for when the player and an object collide, but it shouldn't run when the player walks on a platform.

**How can I set specific functions for collisions between certain categories?** Or, to rephrase my question, **how can I specify different collisions inside of the above-mentioned function?**

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take your contact parameter and use its properties. Specifically bodyA and bodyB will allow you to differentiate between which bodies have had a collision occur. Just put these in an if statement like as follows,

```
    if((bodyA.physicsBody == hero.physicsBody) && (bodyB.physicsBody == platform.physicsBody)){
    //Perform relevant code
    }
    else if((bodyA.physicsBody == hero.physicsBody) && (bodyB.physicsBody == heartPickup.physicsBody)){
//Perform relevant code
}
```

This will allow you to run different sections of code depending on which sprites/physics bodies have been connecting.

Comment: Thanks for that.

A slight modification of that did the trick!